# How to Insert data to a table using codeigniter Active Record queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

MODEL VIEW CONTROLLER PROJECT ON CODE IGNITER - UNABLE TO INSERT DATA TO THE TABLE USING Active Record Class .

**ERROR**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Store::$Storemdl
>
> Filename: controllers/Store.php
>
> Line Number: 49
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\Store.php
> Line: 49
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\index.php
> Line: 292
> Function: require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function signupchk() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\Store.php on line 49
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function signupchk() on a non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Store.php
>
> Line Number: 49
>
> Backtrace:

**MODEL**

```
<?PHP

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function __construct ()
{

    parent ::__construct();

    $this->load->database();
}


function signupchk($username)
{

    $this->db->select('username');

    $this->db->from('users');

    $this->db->where('username,$username');

    $sql = $this->db->get();


    if($sql && $sql->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return false;

    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}



function signup($data)
{


    $data = array(

        'rusername'=> 'username',

        'rpassword'=> 'password',

        'remail'   => 'email',

        'rphone'   => 'phone',

        'rgender'  => 'gender',

        'rqualify' => 'qualification',

    );

    $sql = $this->db->insert('users',$data);
    
    return $sql;

}

}     ?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php


defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Store extends CI_Controller


{


function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}



 function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login');

}

function signup()
{
    $this->load->view('signup');

}


function inserttbl(){
    
    
$username = $this->input->post('username');

$rslt = $this->Storemdl->signupchk($username);

if($result){
    
    $this->Storemdl->signup($this->input->post());
    
    }
    
    else
    
    {
        echo "username already exists";
    }
    
    $this->index();
    
    
}
    
}


?>
```

Comment: why are you using $this->Storemdl->signupchk(); did you using proper alias for the models in config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post the code for model class and, in your model, change this

```
$this->db->where('username,$username');
```

to

```
$this->db->where('username',$username);

or

$this->db->where("username,$username");// single quote to double quote
```

in function `signupchk($username)`

Comment: Active Record queries are the problem. the same code works without any problem with inline queries..

Comment: that where syntax is wrong,replace by what i have given above

Answer (score 0):

Where is your model class? You can try this:

```
 <?PHP

    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Your_model_name extends CI_Model{
    function __construct ()
    {

        parent ::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }


    function signupchk($username)
    {

        $this->db->select('username');

        $this->db->from('users');

        $this->db->where('username,$username');

        $sql = $this->db->get();


        if($sql && $sql->num_rows() > 0)
        {

            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }



    function signup($data)
    {


        $data = array(

            'rusername'=> 'username',

            'rpassword'=> 'password',

            'remail'   => 'email',

            'rphone'   => 'phone',

            'rgender'  => 'gender',

            'rqualify' => 'qualification',

        );

        $sql = $this->db->insert('users',$data);

        return $sql;

    }

    } 
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to load your model.
Add this line in your insert function:

> $this->load->model('Storemdl');